# Creating formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Can anyone help with formula that i am working. I have active list on sheet1 that i am constantly updating. I would like to create another list of specific name from that list in sheet2. Right now, when I add name, I need manually to go to sheet2 and add same information again.

Sheet1

```
Date    Name    Amount 
01/01   John    100 
02/02   Adam    100  
02/28   Mark    100 
03/15   John    200 
04/16   John    200 
05/05   Adam    300 
06/18   Mark    200 
06/20   Adam    50
```

in Sheet2, I would like to create list only with name Mark

Sheet2

```
Date    Name    Amount 
02/28   Mark    100 
06/18   Mark    200
```

With out me going to sheet2 and add information.

Can someone please assist with this formula?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117629/discussion-on-question-by-marko-creating-formula-in-excel).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I know what you want. I cannot upload an image from work, but I will tell you what I have. Upload a link later.
I have a sheet with Name, Amount, and Quarter.
Under these headings, I have the information filled in. So, for the first Quarter, I have

John=300, Adam=100, Mark=100
Arranged in a table.

I do not need an intermediate sheet.
When I figure out how to make a table in Markup, I'll format it that way.

To Summarize:
On Sheet1, I add a column that shows the quarter of the year (assuming Calendar Year). I made that "Column E". The formula for E2 is:
`=INT(MONTH(A2)/4)+1`
`MONTH(A2)` Takes the date in A2, converts it to a number (1=Jan, 2=Feb, etc.)
`/4` There are 4 Quarters in the year: 1-3=Q1; 4-6=Q2, etc.
`INT(MONTH/4)` converts this number to an integer. Anything in Q1 will be 0. Q2 will be 1, etc.
`+1` Adjusts the basis to be 1-4 instead of 0-3.

On the second sheet, I have:
A1=Quarter
B1=Name
C1=Total

A2=1
B2=John
C2 is a formula:
`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!B:B,B2,Sheet1!E:E,A2)`
Note: This assumes the first sheet is called "Sheet1"

From the Excel Help:
`SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,criteria,...)`
Adds the cells specified by a given set of conditions or criteria.

The sum_range is the dollar amounts, which is ColumnC in Sheet 1:
`Sheet1!C:C`
The first criteria_range is the Names, which is ColumB:
`Sheet1!B:B`
The first Criteria Is the Name you've entered into Sheet2!B2, which is John:
`B2`

> This will search Sheet1, ColumB for every entry named John.

The Second Criteria_Range is the Quarter number, which is ColumnE in Sheet1:
`Sheet1!E:E`
The second Criteria is the Quarter Number (1), which you've entered on Sheet2 A2:
`A2`

> This will search Sheet1, ColumnE for every entry containing a 1.

The intersection of these 2 searches, yields a number. All of the numbers are summed and stored in C3.

You can then make Row 3 for Adam, Row 4 for Mark. Copy & Paste.

[here][1]is the link to the spreadsheet with the formulas.  

It's not showing as a link in my browser. Maybe it's my machine. Here  it is "Old School"

https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZNig8XZgNV5lnDMQX4A52FE6MPSk7wUUaD7

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Comment: this works perfectly. Thank you Scottie H.

Comment: Also for those that are working on similar issue. I managed to find simple formula. 

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$9,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9="Mark",ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$1)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN()),"")

Answer (score 0):

Power Query is easier to get the result:

1. Select the Table you need to filter in Sheet1- go to Data- From Table/Range- Open Power Query Editor:

[image]

2. Filter Name Column- Close and Load to:

[image]